# Coin System in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, currency

I have made a coin system (in Unity C#) in the main menu,so I can buy items for them. I would like to pick up the coins in the game scene and add to this score,what I can see in my main menu and in my game scene too.

In the GameManager:

```
public Text coinText;
```

PlayerController Script:

```
    gameManagerScript.coinText.text = "Currency : " + MainGameManager.Instance.currency.ToString();
    gameManagerScript = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
```

When the player pick up the coin : 
`

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        MainGameManager.Instance.currency += 1;
        gameManagerScript.coinText.text = "Currency : " + MainGameManager.Instance.currency.ToString();
    }
```

in the hierarchy I have made a UI -> Text and have dropped in the GameManager.

What I see in the game scene is : Currency: but I don't see how many I have and not add to the currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static fields.
In your GameManager:

```
public static int coins;
```

In Player:

```
GameManager.coins += val
```

You can also access the value using GameManager.coins in MainMenu script.
Note:If you're trying to make this data persistent for different runs you can use PlayerPrefs class:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: So instead of : MainGameManager.Instance.currency += 1 do I use MainGameManager.Instance.currency +=  var

Answer (score 0):

In the PlayerController script you define gameManagerScript after you try to set the text.
Your UI may not be the right size (doesn't fit all your text)
If none of these are the answer, try debugging with `print(string)` or `Debug.log(string)` in the console instead of the ui

Comment: Okay, now it'll save the point / coins but I see it just when I restart the game,

Comment: Have you made sure you're calling OnTriggerEnter? Make sure your collider i set to Trigger. And double check with Debug.Log again if it is actually called

Comment: Yepp , they disappear when I move into them and the points also added to my currency. But I don't see the actually currency in the game .. i need a restart to see it